# Multiple classes in angular components for different logic

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-components

I have two different logics in the same component, for eg if some **useApimApi=true** then the page content needs to be different and if **useApimApi=false** then I need to show different content, how can i couple logic in a single component. I can use if else but there will be lot of chaining and I want to avoid it.

I got some idea from useClass and useFactory Dependency Injection, so i thinking of declaring two classes in my angular component and based on which I can run the particular class. I maybe totally wrong :3. Here's what i am thinking

**some-component.ts**

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { LoaderService } from 'src/app/services/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-some-page',
  templateUrl: './some-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some-page.component.scss']
})
export class SomePageComponent implements OnInit {

// Code logic 1 defined in this class block 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    });
}


export class SomePageComponent2 implements OnInit {

// Code logic 2 defined in this class block 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    });
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { ApiConfig } from '../app/model/apiConfig';
import { API_CONFIG_TOKEN } from './token';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { LoadingSpinnerComponent } from './some/loading-spinner/loading-spinner.component';

const host=environment.host;
const apigURL=environment.apigURL;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OptOutPageComponent,
    OptConfirmScreenComponent,
    LoadingSpinnerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonCoreModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide:API_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue:{
        useApimApi:false,
      } as unknown as ApiConfig
    },
    CookieService,
    DatePipe,
    LoaderService,
    someService,
    {provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass:GlobalHttpInterceptorService,multi:true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
},
)
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: This is not the way to declare components. Remember that a component is basically formed by a template (HTML code) and a logic (TS class), and additionally have styles and another properties. What makes posible to consider typescript class as part of a component is the @Component() decorator, who receives all the metadata to build it.

Comment: The fact of have them in the same file makes no relevant difference. In this case you are considering `SomePageComponent2` a component but is just a typescript class that wrongly implements OnInit. You wont be able to listen to any lifecycle hook since you dont bind to any element in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way to address this is having 2 separate components that you render conditionally via selector in `SomePageComponents`.

Something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="useApimApi">
  <app-child1></app-child1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!useApimApi">
  <app-child2></app-child2>
</div>
```

I have used `<div>` tags and `*ngIf` twice just for simplicity. Of course you could do it better or adapt it to your needs.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="useApimApi; else child2">
  <app-child1></app-child1>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #child2>
  <app-child2></app-child2>
</ng-template>
```

That would be the template of your `SomePageComponents` and in this way you could isolate the logic of `<app-child1>` from `<app-child2>`. Then the only responsability of `SomePageComponents` is to know wich one render.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cybering appreciate it :) This would be my last option to separate the logic into multiple components and thats a good idea too.. Also i am okay with using ngIf if i want to use only one component but what I am concerned about is in the .ts file, as there be like 10-15 if else statements based on business logic and thats not a good practice to use this much if else as it will make the code unreadable.

Comment: You got me wrong. This is the same thing that you' re trying to do. The idea is to put the logic that you have inside `Child1` and the logic of the second class in `Child2`. Then the `SomePageComponent` only have to show `Child1` or `Child2` based on your condition. Note that you are trying yo declare 2 Components but the second one is wrong.